# How to reach a html <span> tag inside a <div> using Java Script?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a `span` tag which placed inside a `div`, like below:

```
<div onclick="doActiveCheckBox('color1')" id="sss"  class="test form-check form-option form-check-inline mb-2">
     <input class="test form-check-input" type="radio" name="color" id="color1" data-bs-label="colorOption" value="/تاریک" checked="">                                
     <label class="form-option-label rounded-circle" for="color1"><span style="border:inherit; border-block-color:purple;"  class="form-option-color rounded-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/ProductColors/green1.jpg)"></span></label>
</div>
```

I want to set a `border` for the `span` tag as the `input` tag is clicked and also don't want to use any `id` in the `span`. I've tried the bellow ways:

1:

```
        var d=document.getElementById("sss").getElementsByTagName("span");
        d.style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";
```

2:

```
        var d=document.getElementById("sss").getElementsByClassName();
        for (var i = 1; i <= d.length; i++) {
            d[1].style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";
        }
```

but none of them worked correctly!
So would anybody help?

Comment: Try chaning d[1] to d[i];

Comment: Also your span element contains 2 style attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use querySelector:
`const d = document.querySelector("#sss span");`

And then you can add style:
`d.style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";`

Answer (score 1):

```
  var d=document.getElementById("sss").getElementsByTagName("span");
                                                 ^//returns an array
d.get.style.border = "thick solid #0000FF";//d[0].style
//┗━━┛
```

There is not a property called `get`, so access the first element since getElementsByTagName return an array.

Comment: Sorry I think I was just distracted. I just edited it, Thanks –

Answer (score 0):

To get the span you can do this

```
var span = document.querySelector("#sss label span");
//do whatever you want with the span
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery method if needed

```
var span = $("#sss label span");
span.css("border", "thick solid #0000FF");
```

or if you're not using #sss just the inputs (may get multiple results)

```
var span = $("input.form-check label span");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could Do These steps to get any ***`HTML ELEMENT`*** and STYLE it using `CSS` or use it using ***`JS`*** by *`document.querySelector`*
1.
[image]

2.
[image]

3.
[image]